# C# Parsing/Accessing Recursive JSON

Tags: c#, json, recursion

I believe I checked all the recursive JSON sections on here, none seem even recursive but whatever. I have a challenge.  How do I iterate through all the depts of this JSON? This JSON has a depth of 200 and that's not even the biggest one.

The JSON "Recursive" is not even a true array, there's only 1 item.

```
{
    "schema": [
        {
            "@id": 1,
            "recursive": [
                {
                    "@Id": 2,
                    "from": {
                        "@id": 1,
                        "recursive": [
                            {
                                "@Id": 2,
                                "from": {
                                    "@id": 1,
                                    "recursive": [
                                        "@Id": 2,
                                        "from" : 49
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My Configuration classes

```
public class rootSchema
{
        [JsonProperty("@id")]
        public int @id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("recursive")]
        public List<recursive> recursive { get; set; }
}
public class from
{
        [JsonProperty("@id")]
        public int @id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("recursive")]
        public List<recursive> recursive { get; set; }
}
public class recursive
{
        [JsonProperty("from")]
        public from from { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("recursive")]
        public List<recursive> recursive { get; set; }
}
```

When I attempt to deserialize this using NewtonSoft.JSON Deserializer, I get an int64 conversion error

```
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 
'Error converting value 49 to type 'Proj.recursive.from'. Path
'recursive[0].from.recursive[0].from.recursive[0].from.recursive[0]
.from.recursive[0].from.recursive[0].from.recursive[0].from.recursive[0]
.from.recursive[0].from.recursive[0].from.recursive[0].from.recursive[0]
.from.recursive[0].from.recursive[0].from.recursive[0].from.recursive[0]
.from.recursive[0].from.recursive[0].from.recursive[0].from.recursive[0]
.from.recursive[0].from.recursive[0].from.recursive[0].from.recursive[0]
.from.recursive[0].from', line 1, position 16273.'
```

I found the cause of this, because in the last element "from", its not a list, its an integer

```
"from": 49,
```

So I am not even sure how to account for a list, & and integer in my definitions. My second issue is, I'm not sure how to iterate through the recursion to get all the "recursive" elements.

Comment: This should not be a problem. Please post a self-contained sample with data. There's no `49` in what you have here.

Comment: If you can point me in the right directon, boy I would be so greatful because I am really stuck.  I had other issues with this JSON, similar issues where the same list could return a list or return an integer. I was able to get around that by evaluating the type, re-serializing, then extracting the part I wanted, and deserializing the extract. I cannot do that with this piece because its the very end node.

Comment: not sure how 500 - Internal Server Error's ask for example was helpful and got up voted but I'm still waiting on a response from anyone. Just sayin'

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Im just going to leave this here

Defs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace theHack
{

    public class Root
    {

        [JsonProperty("ratsnest")]
        public ratsnest ratsnest { get; set; }

    }
    public class ratsnest
    {

        [JsonProperty("garbagepile")]
        public List<object> garbagepile { get; set; }
    }
    public class garbagepile
    {
        [JsonProperty("@id")]
        public int @id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("hammeredhotpoop")]
        public List<object> hammeredhotpoop { get; set; }

    }
    public class hammeredhotpoop
    {
        [JsonProperty("@transitionId")]
        public int @transitionId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nohumorleft")]
        public object nohumorleft { get; set; }

    }

    public class outgoingTransitions
    {
        [JsonProperty("@transitionId")]
        public int @transitionId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nohumorleft")]
        public object nohumorleft { get; set; }
    }
    public class nohumorleft
    {
        [JsonProperty("@id")]
        public int @id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("hammeredhotpoop")]
        public List<object> hammeredhotpoop { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The "logic"... it compiles

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace theHack
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string _data_file = GetFile();

            // going normal, this is expected
            Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(_data_file, new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All, MaxDepth = 200, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

            // can only be 1 root state, everything goes downhill from here
            var parent = root.ratsnest.garbagepile[0];

            //strip all the stupid ids, must repeat this because any element can return any type
            var parentSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parent);

            // begin the descent to only lord knows where
            garbagepile handful = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<garbagepile>(parentSerialized, new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All, MaxDepth = 200, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

            // Can be integer or Jobject, who the heck knows, maybe a trainwreck managed to find its way here
            List<object> incoming = handful.hammeredhotpoop;

            foreach (var crap in incoming)
            {
                // whyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 
                if (crap.GetType() != typeof(int))
                {

                    var rootOfEvil = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(crap);

                    // thank you James Newton King for making the longest constructor I've ever seen

                    hammeredhotpoop firstSeedOfEvil = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<hammeredhotpoop>(rootOfEvil, new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All, MaxDepth = 200, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

                    Console.WriteLine($"@transitionId: {firstSeedOfEvil.transitionId}");

                    var firstHorseman = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(firstSeedOfEvil.nohumorleft);

                    nohumorleft forgotwhatIwasDoing = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<nohumorleft>(firstHorseman, new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All, MaxDepth = 200, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

                    List<object> currentCrap = forgotwhatIwasDoing.hammeredhotpoop;

                    Console.WriteLine($"@id: {forgotwhatIwasDoing.@id}");

                    //loop
                    do
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < currentCrap.Count; i++)
                        {
                            //deserialize the List<object>
                            hammeredhotpoop omgIgiveup = updatemyresume(currentCrap[i]);

                            //output something
                            Console.WriteLine($"@transitionId: {omgIgiveup.transitionId}");

                            // create typed version from this current Transition
                            nohumorleft deserializedfirstHorseman = barreloflaughs(omgIgiveup.nohumorleft);

                            Console.WriteLine($"@id: {deserializedfirstHorseman.@id}");

                            //get the next set of incomingTansitions
                            currentCrap = deserializedfirstHorseman.hammeredhotpoop;
                        }

                    } while (currentCrap != null);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static hammeredhotpoop updatemyresume(object garbageIn)
        {

            if (garbageIn.GetType() != typeof(int))
            {
                var hammerIt = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(garbageIn);

                hammeredhotpoop garbageOut = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<hammeredhotpoop>(hammerIt, new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All, MaxDepth = 200, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

                return garbageOut;
            }
            else { return null; }

        }
        public static nohumorleft barreloflaughs(object garbageIn)
        {
            var hammerIt = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(garbageIn);

            nohumorleft garbageOut = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<nohumorleft>(hammerIt, new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All, MaxDepth = 200, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

            return garbageOut;
        }
        public static string GetFile()
        {
            var fileName = @"C:\Users\me\source\test.json";
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(fileName))
                {
                    string text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
                    file.Close();
                    return text;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File does not exist");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

a representation of the JSON

```
{
    "ThisWasActuallyAnArray": [
        {
            "surprising": [
                {
                    "typeNull": null,
                    "connectionId": "233ad541-7468-49b5-a7bb-dddddd",
                    "id": 29531,
                    "name": "funnyTown",
                    "letsEmbedSomeJson": "{\"id\":\"234\",..."
                }
            ],
            "type": "",
            "id": 46243,
            "name": "somestring"
        }
    ],
    "ratsnest": {
        "whynot": null,
        "garbagepile": [
            {
                "@id": 1,
                "subData": null,
                "subDataClass": "",
                "id": "123-abc",
                "hammeredhotpoop": [
                    {
                        "@transitionId": 4,
                        "datastuff": {
                            "abool": false,
                            "astring": "anyway",
                            "anInt": 1
                        },
                        "anotherRabbitHole2": 3,
                        "id": "123",
                        "name": "...",
                        "anotherRabbitHole": {
                            "@id": 5,
                            "someData": {
                                "setting1": true,
                                "Grouping": "FooBar",
                                "str1": "60",
                                "aBool": true,
                                "id": 5
                            },
                            "config": "somedata",
                            "id": "123",
                            "nohumorleft": {},
                            "name": "",
                            "notes": ""
                        },
                        "nohumorleft": {
                            "@id": 9,
                            "listData": {},
                            "id": "123",
                            "hammeredhotpoop": [
                                {
                                    "@transitionId": 4,
                                    "datastuff": {
                                        "abool": false,
                                        "astring": "anyway",
                                        "anInt": 1
                                    },
                                    "anotherRabbitHole2": 3,
                                    "id": "123",
                                    "name": "...",
                                    "anotherRabbitHole": {
                                        "@id": 5,
                                        "someData": {
                                            "setting1": true,
                                            "Grouping": "FooBar",
                                            "str1": "60",
                                            "aBool": true,
                                            "id": 5
                                        },
                                        "config": "somedata",
                                        "id": "123",
                                        "nohumorleft": {},
                                        "name": "",
                                        "notes": ""
                                    },
                                    "nohumorleft": [
                                        {
                                            "@id": 9,
                                            "listData": {},
                                            "id": "123",
                                            "hammeredhotpoop": [
                                                {
                                                    "@transitionId": 4,
                                                    "datastuff": {
                                                        "abool": false,
                                                        "astring": "anyway",
                                                        "anInt": 1
                                                    },
                                                    "anotherRabbitHole2": 3,
                                                    "id": "123",
                                                    "name": "...",
                                                    "anotherRabbitHole": {
                                                        "@id": 5,
                                                        "someData": {
                                                            "setting1": true,
                                                            "Grouping": "FooBar",
                                                            "str1": "60",
                                                            "aBool": true,
                                                            "id": 5
                                                        },
                                                        "config": "somedata",
                                                        "id": "123",
                                                        "nohumorleft": {},
                                                        "name": "",
                                                        "notes": ""
                                                    },
                                                    "nohumorleft": {
                                                        "@id": 9,
                                                        "listData": {},
                                                        "id": "123",
                                                        "hammeredhotpoop": [
                                                            {
                                                                "@transitionId": 4,
                                                                "datastuff": {
                                                                    "abool": false,
                                                                    "astring": "anyway",
                                                                    "anInt": 1
                                                                },
                                                                "anotherRabbitHole2": 3,
                                                                "id": "123",
                                                                "name": "...",
                                                                "anotherRabbitHole": {
                                                                    "@id": 5,
                                                                    "someData": {
                                                                        "setting1": true,
                                                                        "Grouping": "FooBar",
                                                                        "str1": "60",
                                                                        "aBool": true,
                                                                        "id": 5
                                                                    },
                                                                    "config": "somedata",
                                                                    "id": "123",
                                                                    "name": "",
                                                                    "notes": "",
                                                                    "nohumorleft": 49
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "3",
                                        "2",
                                        "1",
                                        "upskill",
                                        true
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    5,
                    4,
                    3,
                    2,
                    1,
                    "LOL"
                ],
                "notes": "",
                "someInt": 0,
                "type": "",
                "hammeredhotboogers": [],
                "listData": {}
            }
        ]
    }
}
```